# Python AppEngine Sort Query Object Through Two Attributes

Tags: python, sorting, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model

```
class Neighborhood(model) {
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  city = EncodedProperty(encoder=_get_city_name)
}
```

and I would like to retrieve all of the Neighborhood objects and sort them through both "name" and "city" attributes. Initially, I tried

```
def retrieveAndSort()
  query=Neighborhood.all()
  query.order("name")
  query.order("city")
  return query
```

but after some further research, it seems GAE doesn't support sorting for EncodedProperty objects. Then, I tried to sort the data in Python after retrieving the query object with the `sort()` method but the Query object doesn't have this method. Lastly, I tried to sort the Query object with the `sorted()` method with the code:

`neighborhoods = sorted(neighborhoods, key=attrgetter('city', 'name'))`

and it almost worked. However, data seemed jumbled and I received some output like the following below.

```
Abu Dhabi - Al Maryah Island
Minneapolis - Montrose
Atlanta - Buckhead
Atlanta - Home Park
Atlantic City - Boardwalk
Atlantic City - Marina
...
California - Saint Helena
California - Yountville
New York City - Central Park
Charlotte - South End
Charlotte - Third End
...
```

I have absolutely no idea why this occurs other and would appreciate any help possible.

**Edit:** 
Shorter sample output:

```
New York City - Meatpacking District
New York City - Brooklyn
New York City - Midtown West
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fetch the entities and then sort it.

```
neighborhoods = Neighborhood.all().fetch(1000)
neighborhoods = sorted(neighborhoods, key=attrgetter('city', 'name'))
```

Comment: Can you show the code lines which assigns  neighborhoods ?

Comment: What do you mean by assign neighborhoods? To get the current result I have now, I have the Neighborhood model, a retrieveAndSort() function that only order the query by "name" and returns it, and the following code in another file `neighborhoods = retrieveAndSort()`, `neighborhoods = sorted(neighborhoods, key=attrgetter('city', 'name'))`

Comment: When you call retrieveAndSort() it returns just a query object it is not a collection of entities. so applying sorted on that object make no sense. Did you try my code at all? I just corrected a typo in it as well.

Comment: I ran your code and I received an error stating that fetch requires an argument inside its parameters. I also tried using run() which is supposed to return an iterable but I still get the same results.

Comment: sorry my bad!  fetch takes a parameter to specify the number of records you need. try fetch(1000) to see if sorting at least working. Then we can figure out how to get all your entities and get it sorted.

Comment: I tried fetch(1000) and it works. However, sadly, I still receive the same output as before.

Comment: One more question what is EncodedProperty ? is this your own class? Can you provide the code for that class?

Comment: Ah it seems to be a class someone else made. This is probably why the sort didn't work as was supposed to. Thanks for narrowing this down

Comment: My guess is city is stored in db as a code or something and this EnCoderClass converts it into city name .Just a guess not seeing the code.

Comment: Ah finally figured it out. It was a very careless mistake of mine. The sort worked perfectly fine, it's just that I had many objects with similar names and there was a slight typo error in my soy template which caused it to go wonky. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged as gae-datastore but "EncodedProperty" isn't a datastore property type.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses

The model should be:

```
class Neighborhood(db.model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    city = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Then your query function could simply be:

```
def retrieveAndSort():
    """
    Returns everything in Neighborhood model alphabetically
    """
    query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Neighborhood ORDER BY city DESC')
    for place in query:
        print "{0} - {1}".format(place.city, place.name)
```